# Accepting an answer to a typo question

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

On SO, I asked a [question that, after a bit of experimentation, ended up being a typo question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063502/seemingly-identical-values-not-evaluating-as-equal-in-excel) There was one person who, unable to comment (not sure why), tried to help me troubleshoot by giving an answer. After I realized my mistake that the problem wasn't necessarily with my code, I accepted the answer from the person attempting to help me as "thanks" sort of. I then went to delete my question, but found I couldn't since an answer had been recently accepted (I then flagged it to be closed.) My questions are;

1) Should I have accepted the answer in the first place? Even if they helped me arrive at what the problem was, was it poor form to accept any answer to a question that, in the end, turned out to be a typo?

2) Should I un-accept the answer? It seems kind of cruel to give him the reputation then immediately take it from him, but did they really "deserve" it in this context? It may be worth noting that they didn't have much karma in the first place, and I may not have realized what the issue was if they hadn't stepped in. Would they lose the reputation anyway if the question was deleted/closed?

Comment: It looks like the answer received an upvote in addition to the accept. Together, the two gave the user the ~25 rep they needed to get the comment anywhere privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People accept answers for a variety of reasons.

In a perfect world, which I assume you'd like to facilitate by asking this question, you should only accept an answer that:

1. is actually an answer to your question.
2. is *correct* and helps you solve your problem.

If the answer fails to meet these two tests, you shouldn't accept it. If it fails to meet test one, you should flag it as NAA. If it fails to meet test two, you should down vote it. If multiple answers pass these tests, you get the fun job of deciding which you prefer - or which answer you find explained themselves better or provided the actual solution you used. This does not have to be the highest-voted answer.

In that perfect world, yes, you would unaccept the answer. Doing so will make it possible for you to delete your question, as well. You shouldn't be "rewarding" someone for abusing the system by writing what should be a comment as an answer.

But, in the end, it's all up to you. No one can tell you what you must do or even change your accept status other than you.

---

More information:

The reason they couldn't comment is that commenting requires 50 rep on the site. Their answer to your question gained them the rep they need to write comments. Yes, removing your accept and deleting the question will cost them that ability but the restriction is there for a reason. Comments should not be made as answers any more than answers should be written as comments.

If the question is *closed*, no, they won't lose the reputation. If it is *deleted*, they will. If a moderator on SO chooses to delete the question as a result of your flag, the rep will be gone.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer

Answer (score 1):

It's totally up to you whether you accept an answer or not. No one can do it for you and no one should tell you which answer to accept or not accept. The answer was useful as it helped you solve the problem. These are the criteria for upvoting and accepting answers.

The answer is almost an answer, it's phrased like you would a comment asking for clarification, but it could be rewritten to be a proper answer, so it's a borderline case.

However, if you want to delete the question you will have to unaccept the answer so that it meets the criteria to allow deletion. You can only delete a question if it has no answers or one only answer without upvotes. In this context an accept counts as an upvote.

If you do unaccept the answer the answerer will lose the 15 points. There is no way round this.

If the question is OK then just leaving it there is also acceptable.

Comment: `The answer was useful as it helped you solve the problem. These are the criteria for upvoting and accepting answers.` I'll try to keep this in mind in the future, thanks

Comment: @A.Williams the fact that other people might not agree that the answer is useful is not really relevant ;)